# How to verify schedules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, firebase, momentjs

I need to verify if a certain time are between another two. For example:

Today: Thursday, 11:39PM

The store X is open from 00:00AM to 11:59PM on thursdays (in plural, its recorrent). So, a function isOpen returns true.

I have made a workaround for this, writing this on the database (Firebase):

```
{
  "open" : 7200000,
  "day" : "Thursday",
  "close" : 93540000
}
```

Where open and close is milliseconds from 01/01/1970

In the function I check if there is a day in the database that matches the current day, after this i need to create a Date from 01/01/1970 with 11:39PM and check if open is smaller and close is bigger than current time.

```
let open = false;
if (store.schedule) {
    for (sch in store.schedule) {
        if (store.schedule[sch].day == day) {
            open = self.checkHour(store.schedule[sch].open, store.schedule[sch].close);
        }
    }
}
return open;
```

And checkHour

```
checkHour = function (open, close) {
    return moment().year(1970).month(0).date(1).isBetween(moment(open), moment(close));
};
```

PS: I'm using moment.js

Terrible, terrible solution, I know. I'm sure there is a better way.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of your code.

Comment: Also, explain what datebase you're using.

Comment: @Soviut I put an example in the question. I'm using Firebase

Comment: You should update your tags to include firebase since that's an important part of the question.

Comment: @Soviut actually the important part is the algorithm for compare recurrent times. I just mentioned that the data was in the database, but could be locally

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to manually query your database, let the database do its own querying.

You never explained which database you're using, but most a "datetime" field of some sort you can use. You can then pass a formatted date string in your query and check if it's greater than the `open` field and less than the `close` field.

For example, in SQL you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE {date} >= open and {date} <= close;
```

In this case `{date}` would be the formatted date you're passing into the query.

That said, if you already have the store in question, you can simply compare the data you already have in your javascript object.

```
var store = {
  "open" : 7200000,
  "day" : "Thursday",
  "close" : 93540000
};

var now = Date.now();

if (now >= store.open && now <= store.close) {
  // you are in range
}
```

Comment: open and close are times from 1970, Date.now() will aways be greater than both.

Comment: Thanks for explain the query, I dont realize that I'm doing wrong, I'm going to redo searching straight into the database